# Receive Fence callbacks when app is killed

Tags: android, android-geofence, google-awareness

I'm using Fence Api in Google Awareness Api to create a geofence and trigger it when the user enters or exists the location. But this is working fine if the app is running. If the app is killed, I'm not receiving any status.

I've a static broadcast receiver in manifest which will receive the pending intent for fence callbacks.

I'm neither unregistering reciever nor the fence.

I don't know why I'm not able to receive the fence callbacks when the app is killed.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the service as a foregroundservice and/or binding the service. It'll be easier to answer if you post some code.

Comment: post a comment if you need more informations from the asker